# Unable to get POST form data with PHP echo input

Tags: php, html, post

I explain you my problem. In my form, a part of the inputs are directly written in the html code, while another part is written in php in a condition (which here is true).

When I send the form and I `var_dump` the variable `$_POST`, only the data of the inputs written in the HTML have been sent. 
On the other hand, it is impossible to retrieve the data of the inputs written in the PHP condition.

Do you understand why I have this problem?
don't hesitate to let me know if you need more details
Thanks for your help.

```
<form action="php/addcart.php" method="post">

        <?php if(!empty($kitShortDesc)) : ?> // Variable is not empty
            <div class='product-associates' style='margin-bottom: 20px;'>
                <div class='product-associates-checkbox'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][kit]' value='<?php echo kit;?>'/> 
                    <input type='checkbox' name='cartContent[name][kit][kitShortDesc]' value='<?php echo $kitShortDesc;?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][kit][kitLongDesc]' value='<?php echo $kitLongDesc;?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][kit][kitPrice]' value='<?php echo $kitPrice;?>'>
                </div>
                <div class='product-associates-container'>
                    <p>Kit Embrayage : <?php echo $kitShortDesc;?></p>
                    <p>Prix : <?php echo $kitPrice;?>€</p>
                    <a class='product-associates-learnmore' href=''>En savoir plus</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name]' value='<?php echo $name;?>'/> 
    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][brand]' value='<?php echo $brand;?>'/> 
    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][model]' value='<?php echo $model;?>'/> 
    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][category]' value='<?php echo $category;?>'/> 
    <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name][price]' value='<?php echo $price;?>'/> 

    <div class="product-final-price">
        <input type="submit" value="Ajouter au panier">
    </div>

</form>
```

result of `var_dump($_POST['cartContent'])` in `addcart.php` :

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> array(4) { ["brand"]=> string(4) "Audi" ["model"]=> string(2) "A1" ["category"]=> string(8) "1.2 TFSI" ["price"]=> string(3) "400" } }
```

As you can see, there is no array `[kit]`

Comment: Put  <input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name]' value='<?php echo $name;?>'/> to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue identified.
This following line should be at the top position just after the FORM declaration.

```
<input type='hidden' name='cartContent[name]' value='<?php echo $name;?>'/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What's the consequence if the line above is left where it is? As in, _what is the issue_, actually?

Comment: I don't really understand why, but indeed it works now, thanks!
EDIT: nvm I just understood why, I name the value of the input cartContent[name][kit] while I create cartContent[name] after, so the array [name] of cartContent[name][kit] does not exist yet.

Comment: @VeeN actually what's happening is that _the deeper parts of that array DO exist initially_ but then you _re-create the variable_ with `cartContent[name]` placed after the earlier definitions. In fact it seems you re-define the array as a string, and then again start using it as an array. I don't think you're getting the value for `cartContent[name]` either, since it stops being a string.